# 'OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run sort on the data imported from excel but getting below error. Why after importing into dataframe its saying its ordered dictionary?

-Error:

```
'OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet_name=None)
dfs
data_df = (dfs.sort(['Date','Tank','Time']).groupby(['Date','Tank']))
data_df
```

DF:

```
OrderedDict([(u'Sheet1',
                       Date      Time  Tank  Sales  Quantity  Delivery
              0  2018-01-01  06:30:00     1    100      3444         0
              1  2018-01-01  07:00:00     1    200      3144         0
              2  2018-01-01  05:30:00     1    100      2900         0
              3  2018-01-01  07:30:00     1    200      2800         0
              4  2018-01-01  06:30:00     2     50      3000         0
              5  2018-01-01  07:00:00     2    100      2950         0
              6  2018-01-01  05:30:00     2    150      2800         0
              7  2018-01-01  07:30:00     2    100      2704         0
              8  2018-01-02  06:30:00     1    100      3444         0
              9  2018-01-02  07:00:00     1    200      3144         0
              10 2018-01-02  05:30:00     1    100      2900        50
              11 2018-01-02  07:30:00     1    200      2800         0
              12 2018-01-02  06:30:00     2     50      3000         0
              13 2018-01-02  07:00:00     2    100      2950         0
              14 2018-01-02  05:30:00     2    150      2800        50
              15 2018-01-02  07:30:00     2    100      2704         0)])
```

Comment: FYI, `sort` is deprecated use `sort_values`

Comment: Provide  a `sheet_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because parameter `sheet_name=None` in [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

> **sheet_name** : string, int, mixed list of strings/ints, or None, default 0
>   ...
>   **None** -> `All sheets as a dictionary of DataFrames`

Also check [`specifying sheets`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#specifying-sheets).

So you need no parameter for return first sheetname:

```
df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
```

Or specify `sheet_name` if necessary:

```
df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Comment: while first option worked. Second option " df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')" is not working getting below error.

XLRDError: No sheet named <'sheet1'>